# IS there any way to remove or hide warnings from reactjs project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

My app has lot of warnings which irritate me, so now i want to remove or hide all that warnings, so is there any way to do this.

Comment: Warnings are there for a reason. You are supposed to do something to overcome the problem. Silencing them defeats the purpose.

Comment: But, i want the control over that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is but It is not a good idea to supress warning, you should do something to fix it.
Still here it is:
suppose:

```
import Something from './Something';
```

But you are not using it. So you add this to the line above import to supress warning.

```
// eslint-disable-next-line
```

So it would be

```
// eslint-disable-next-line 
import Something from './Something';
```

BOOM, your warning is gone.

Comment: Thanks for reply,But  i am asking about the cmd to disable all kind of warning and error something like --silent.

Comment: use `/* eslint-disable */` to disable all warning in a file. This would be close to what you want.

Comment: Check this out `https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#brunch`. This will hide all react warnings. But it should be production build of your app.